# Add radio button in powershell output for selection

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script in PowerShell where I need to select items from output to do the job. For example:-
Get-Process | Out-GridView
I want to select the items I am get in the Grid and then move ahead like kill the process i have selected.
I am stuck on how to add radio buttons or is there another way to select the items in output i see.

Comment: Add `-PassThru` to `Out-GridView`, this will give you the ability to select items in the Grid

Comment: It's as simple as `Get-Process | Out-GridView -PassThru | Stop-Process`. You select items by clicking in the listbox, as you would do in Explorer, for instance.

Comment: Thank You very much. Functionally it is working. Is there a way i can add a selection box in the gridview instead of clicking on the listbox? Thanks again

Comment: Nope. If you want a different UI, have a look into [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: ' Manish Shukla'. if you mean so users can select more than one line, then OGV, provides that by default without any effort to glossy it up. Just use the normal CRTL+LeftMouseClick. You can do some interesting things with OGV, but that requires way mode code anyway, thus as noted, create your own WinForm/WPF GUI. [However, the has been a feature ask since 2020 for the checkbox thing](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12074).